# My laptop acer aspire 5720 suddenly turn off randomly

Tags: laptop

For a while I have watched that when I am watching a movie online for half hour or 45 minutes followed it turn off sudenly. And when this happend I must wait around 5 to 10 minutes to turn on it again becauase if I turn on it inmediately that the laptop got turn off it sent me to a black screen with this symbol - intermittent and I must turn off it manualy because it doesnt give the option to turn off automatically. I would like to know what can I do for fix this problem cause some times I have works that I have not save it and many times I lost it. I will apreciate any help

Comment: If you feel the underside of the laptop is it getting excessively hot? A laptop cooler might help. You can also try blowing compressed air through the vents to clear out dust. Opening it up and cleaning will be best, but I don't recommend doing this if you're the least bit unsure.

Answer (score 0):

When processor reach the max temp for self protection it shuts down to avoid Heating Up.
Seach if there are any BIOS updates for your model.
Or Clean it up.